# How to change the position of an image in tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I'm trying to move an image into the left side of the screen but I don't know how to do that with tkinter. Could you please help me?

My code:

```
root = tk.Tk()
with urllib.request.urlopen(pic) as connection:
raw_data = connection.read()
im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(raw_data))
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=600, height=300)
canvas.grid()
widget = tk.Label(root, image=image)
widget.grid(ipadx=0,ipady=0)
root.mainloop()
```

The "pic" variable link: https://cdn.myanimelist.net/r/100x140/images/anime/6/73245.webp?s=95382e6f29a0093a04b1479145c18d61

[image: Interface]

Comment: Please look at [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20201111175154/http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm). Then look at the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html). If you still don't get it, then ask the questio on stackoverflow.

Comment: Layout questions like this are fairly useless. Tkinter provides a documented method named  `place` which lets you place an image precisely where you want it. However, in the context of a real application with more than a single widget, `place` is almost never the right choice if you want to create a responsive UI. So, you can get an answer by reading available documentation or we can give a literal answer to your question, but it won't necessarily lead to a good UI.

Comment: Are you trying to place image on canvas or on root?